# How to add new rows with different value in one column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Basically I have a vector `names` of all names, and a dataframe `df` with a BIN (0/1) field and a NAME field. For every row with `BIN==0`, I want to create a duplicate row but with 1 instead and add it to the bottom of `df` with a different name. Here's what I have to select a new name, given the current name:

```
sample(names[names!=name], 1)
```

But I'm not sure how to vectorize this and furthermore add it to `df` with the same data from BIN.

EDIT:
Sample data:

```
df = data.frame(BIN=c(1,0,1), NAME=c("alice","bob","cate"))
names = c("alice","bob","cate","dan")
```

I got closer with something like this:

```
rbind(df, df %>% filter(BIN == 0) %>%
    mutate(NAME = sample(names[names!=NAME],1)))
```

But I get an error: In binattr(e1, e2): length(e1) not a multiple of length(e2).

Comment: can you generate some sample data so we can run your code ?

Comment: @JackBrookes See edit, let me know if you need more

Comment: What would be your expected output from your provided dateframe?

Comment: How do you want the "new name" to be selected - does it need to be random? Or is any different name okay? And how big is your real data - trying to figure out how much we need to worry about efficiency.

Comment: @Gregor Not too big, under 10k rows. I think random is necessary in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple approach. I think it's pretty straightforward, let me know if you have questions:

```
rename = subset(df, BIN == 0)
rename$NEW_NAME = sample(names, size = nrow(rename), replace = TRUE)
while(any(rename$NAME == rename$NEW_NAME)) {
  matches = rename$NAME == rename$NEW_NAME
  rename$NEW_NAME[matches] = sample(names, size = sum(matches), replace = TRUE)
}
rename$BIN = 1
rename$NAME = rename$NEW_NAME
rename$NEW_NAME = NULL

result = rbind(df, rename)
result
#    BIN  NAME
# 1    1 alice
# 2    0   bob
# 3    1  cate
# 21   1 alice
```

Here's another approach, less clear but more efficient. This is the "right" way to do it, but it requires a little bit more thought and explanation.

```
df$NAME = factor(df$NAME, levels = names)
rename = subset(df, BIN == 0)
n = length(names)
# we will increment each level number with a random integer from
# 1 to n - 1 (with a mod to make it cyclical)
offset = sample(1:(n - 1), size = nrow(rename), replace = TRUE)
adjusted = (as.integer(rename$NAME) + offset) %% n
# reconcile 1-indexed factor levels with 0-indexed mod operator
adjusted[adjusted == 0] = n
rename$NAME = names[adjusted]
rename$BIN = 1
result = rbind(df, rename)
```

(or, rewritten for `dplyr`)

```
df = mutate(df, NAME = factor(NAME, levels = names))
n = length(names)
df %>% filter(BIN == 0) %>%
  mutate(
    offset = sample(1:(n - 1), size = n(), replace = TRUE),
    adjusted = (as.integer(NAME) + offset) %% n,
    adjusted = if_else(adjusted == 0, n, adjusted),
    NAME = names[adjusted],
    BIN = 1
  ) %>%
  select(-offset, -adjusted) %>%
  rbind(df, .)
```

Since your issue is the vectorization part, I'd recommend testing answer on a sample case with more than one BIN 0 row, I used this:

```
df = data.frame(BIN=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0), NAME=rep(c("alice","bob","cate"), 3))
```

---

And, because I was curious, here's a benchmark for 10k rows with 26 names. Results first, code below:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq        max neval
#       while_loop  34.070438  34.327020  37.53357  35.548047  39.922918  46.206454    10
#        increment   1.397617   1.458592   1.88796   1.526512   2.123894   3.196104    10
#  increment_dplyr  24.002169  24.681960  25.50568  25.374429  25.750548  28.054954    10
#         map_char 346.531498 347.732905 361.82468 359.736403 374.648635 383.575265    10
```

The "clever" way is by far the fastest. My guess is the `dplyr` slowdown is because we can't do the direct replacement of only the relevant bits of `adjusted`, and instead have to add the overhead of `if_else`. That and we are actually adding columns to the data frame for `adjusted` and `offset` rather than dealing with vectors. This is enough to make it almost as slow as the `while` loop approach, which is still 10x faster than the `map_chr` which has to go one row at a time.

```
nn = 10000
df = data.frame(
  BIN = sample(0:1, size = nn, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
  NAME = factor(sample(letters, size = nn, replace = TRUE), levels = letters)
)

get.new.name <- function(c){
    return(sample(names[names!=c],1))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  while_loop = {
    rename = subset(df, BIN == 0)
    rename$NEW_NAME = sample(names, size = nrow(rename), replace = TRUE)
    while (any(rename$NAME == rename$NEW_NAME)) {
      matches = rename$NAME == rename$NEW_NAME
      rename$NEW_NAME[matches] = sample(names, size = sum(matches), replace = TRUE)
    }
    rename$BIN = 1
    rename$NAME = rename$NEW_NAME
    rename$NEW_NAME = NULL
    result = rbind(df, rename)
  }, 
  increment = {
    rename = subset(df, BIN == 0)
    n = length(names)
    # we will increment each level number with a random integer from
    # 1 to n - 1 (with a mod to make it cyclical)
    offset = sample(1:(n - 1), size = nrow(rename), replace = TRUE)
    adjusted = (as.integer(rename$NAME) + offset) %% n
    # reconcile 1-indexed factor levels with 0-indexed mod operator
    adjusted[adjusted == 0] = n
    rename$NAME = names[adjusted]
    rename$BIN = 1
  },
  increment_dplyr = {
    n = length(names)
    df %>% filter(BIN == 0) %>%
      mutate(
        offset = sample(1:(n - 1), size = n(), replace = TRUE),
        adjusted = (as.integer(NAME) + offset) %% n,
        adjusted = if_else(adjusted == 0, n, adjusted),
        NAME = names[adjusted],
        BIN = 1
      ) %>%
      select(-offset,-adjusted)
  },
  map_char = {
    new.df <- df %>% filter(BIN == 0) %>%
      mutate(NAME = map_chr(NAME, get.new.name)) %>%
      mutate(BIN = 1)
  },
  times = 10
)
```

Comment: Haven't tried it, I suppose it works but it seems somewhat...hacky

Comment: It's definitely a bit hacky. Not too bad really though - unless your list of possible names is *very* short it will settle into a solution quite quickly (and be a lot faster than going one row at a time - your method isn't working because you'd need to add a `%>% rowwise() %>%` - but that will be horribly inefficient). But I just added the "right" way to do it - randomly selecting an offset number of factor levels to increment.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just to be sure which part/line prevents the same name from being chosen?

Comment: The `1:(n - 1)` instead of `1:n` prevents the same name from being chosen. Imagine the names are in a circle. We pick a random integer of how many places to rotate the circle to get the new name. `n` would be a full rotation, ending up with the same name. Any number 1 to n - 1 is a different name.

Comment: Hahaha okay you take accepted answer, well-deserved

Answer (score 1):

Well I didn't intend to answer my own question but I did find a simpler solution. I think it's better than using `rowwise()` but I don't know if it's necessarily the most efficient way.

```
library(tidyverse)

get.new.name <- function(c){
    return(sample(names[names!=c],1))
}

new.df <- rbind(df, df %>% filter(BIN == 0) %>%
    mutate(NAME = map_chr(NAME, get.new.name)) %>%
    mutate(BIN = 1)
```

`map_char` ended up being pretty important instead of just `map` since the latter would return a weird list of lists.

Comment: For most efficient way, see the addition to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

A little weird but I think this should be what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(BIN=c(1,0,1), NAME=c("alice","bob","cate"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names <- c("alice","bob","cate","dan")

df %>% 
  mutate(NAME_new = ifelse(BIN == 0, sample(names, n(), replace = TRUE), NA)) %>% 
  gather(name_type, NAME, NAME:NAME_new, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(BIN = ifelse(name_type == "NAME_new", 1, BIN)) %>% 
  select(-name_type)
```

Output:

```
  BIN  NAME
1   1 alice
2   0   bob
3   1  cate
4   1 alice
```

Comment: This does nothing to ensure that the new name is different from the old name. If you `set.seed(1)` then `bob` is replaced with `bob`.